# Creating an event handler like socket.io

Tags: javascript, node.js

I want to create a class which when special events are triggered an event handler like with socket.io is called.

Socket.io does it like this:

```
 socket.on('chat', func () { //Callback });
 socket.on('connect', func () { //Callback });
```

How can I create these event handler with different name (eg. chat, connect)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're just looking to create an event emitter, check out the Node documentation. https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v6.x/docs/api/events.html